# Backup app's fingerprint data and restore

Tags: security, backup, restore, fingerprint

I have one app on my device locked with fingerprints. I want to back up this app, delete it, and restore it again without a need to log in again. So it should work again with fingerprint without any need to log in again and attach fingerprint.

Basically, to restore the app at the same status as it was before deleting. Is this even possible even with root access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not possible even with root. And rightly so, since accessing fingerprint data is a huge security risk.

Android stores fingerprint data in [Trusted Execution Environment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_execution_environment) and can't be accessed even with root. This data doesn't leave the device nor is it a part of app data. For more details, see key points related to the question
(from our sister sites) :

- [Android - Where and how securely is fingerprint information stored in a device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632225/android-where-and-how-securely-is-fingerprint-information-stored-in-a-device)

> All fingerprint data must be secured within sensor hardware or trusted memory so that images of your fingerprint are inaccessible

> Root access must not compromise fingerprint data

- [Does biometric authentication in Android transfer any biometric data to the app?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248168/does-biometric-authentication-in-android-transfer-any-biometric-data-to-the-app)

> Biometrics never leave hardware-backed keystore (TEE)

> So no, your fingerprint data should never be accessible to any apps

Cracking TEE is not a trivial exercise (theoretically possible, I guess) - if  one could, it breaches the entire security system of Android.